# Last year's equivalent for a date based on day of week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How would I then get the last year's equivalent for both:

Previous weeks Mondays date last year
Previous weeks Sundays date last year

based on the value I got for:

--start of last week this year

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0)
```

--end of last week this year

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6)
```

So, based on today's date (06/01/2016) I get the following for this year:

> Previous Mondays date this year = 28/12/2015
>
> Previous Sundays date this year = 03/01/2016

I would like to achieve:

> Previous Mondays date last year = 29/12/2014
> Previous Sundays date last year = 04/01/2015

Where the syntax would take care of the leap year issue every 4 years.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a few more examples, with special attention paid to the boundaries e.g. your first code, for me, seems to transition between Saturdays and Sundays - if you ask for "last week" when today's date is 2016-01-03, it returns 2015-12-28 - 2016-01-03, I.e. a range that includes the current Sunday. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you asking for the beginning and end dates of the week before the week last year with the same number as the current week this year? if so, something like this might work? `SET DATEFIRST 2
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK,DATEPART(Wk,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0))-1,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())) AS PreviousMonday`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, dateadd(year,-1,GETDATE())), 0)  as 'Previous monday date last year '


SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, dateadd(year,-1,GETDATE())), 6)  as 'Previous Sundays date last year '
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It still doesn't seem to sort the leap year issue out. I changed getdate() to DECLARE @testdate datetime;
SET @testdate='20160229, I now get Previous Monday date last year='2015-02-16' and Previous Sunday date last year='2015-02-22' but I would've thought this would be '2015-03-02' and '2015-03-08' respectively. Changing @testdate='20160222' gets me the same answers as '20160229' which is correct for testdate '20160222' but wrong for '20160229'. Changing @testdate=20160307 gets me '2015-02-23' and '2015-03-01' but I thought I should get '2015-03-09' and '2015-03-15'.

Comment: I changed it to the below and it seems to work--start of last week

SELECT cast(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, dateadd(week,-52,@testdate)), 0) as date)

--end of last week

SELECT cast(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, dateadd(week,-52,@testdate)), 6) as date)

Comment: @beatrice1711 - I'm especially surprised at your "input is `20160307`, output is `'2015-03-09' and '2015-03-15'`" - since those seem to be a "future date" from last year. That's why I asked you to enhance your question and add a few worked examples, so that we can clearly understand your requirements. Leap days can be problematic, but there are so many ways you *might* want to deal with them that just saying "sort the leap year issue out" doesn't really give us enough guidance.

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem  @beatrice1711 are you facing only problem with leap year .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, dateadd(year,-1,GETDATE())), 0)  as 'Previous monday date '


SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, dateadd(year,-1,GETDATE())), 6)  as 'Previous Sundays date '
```

its too simple

Comment: what is the benefit of your query if we comapre it with @G.Nagababu's query. both query has same SQL syntax.